# How to merge dataframes using a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following input dataframe,

df1,

```
 col1_1 | col2 | ....
AB0123  |      |
0678    |      |
AB0567  |      | 
0921    |      |
6752    |      |
```

and the following lookup dataframe

df2,

```
col1   | col2 | col3 |...
AB0123 |      |  abc |
AB0567 |      |  dfe | 
       |0678  |  ghi |
       |0921  |  jkl |
       |6752  |  mno |
```

Final output df,

```
 col1_1 | col1_or_col2 | col2....
AB0123  |     abc      |
0678    |     ghi      |
AB0567  |     dfe      |
0921    |     jkl      |
6752    |     mno      |
```

what I have in my mind is to create two temp columns in the output df and then making a separate function* to generate col1_or_col2,

*The function will check for each row and take the final not-empty value between temp_col2 or temp_col3

```
 col1  | temp_col1 | temp_col2 | col1_or_col2
AB0123 |   abc     |           |    abc
0678   |           |     ghi   |    ghi
AB0567 |   dfe     |           |    dfe
0921   |           |     jkl   |    jkl
6752   |           |     mno   |    mno
```

Is there a pandas function that I can use to solve the above problem efficiently?

Comment: What does this means: "on the basis of col2 and col3 from lookup df1"?

Comment: why do you shift col2 values to col1? could you elaborate the logic a bit more

Comment: Please add an example of the "input" dataframe

Comment: I have edited the question and hopefully it provides more insights @Dani Mesejo

Comment: I have edited the question and hopefully it provides more insights @anky

Answer (score 1):

You can do this elegantly incorporating `pop` in addition to my comment. This code updates the `col1` of the second dataframe `df2` by filling `NaN` values from  `col1` with `col2` values, while simultaneously using `pop` to remove the now unnecessary `col2` from the dataframe. Now, you merge this new `df2` with `df1`. Make sure your merge columns are of `object` data type prior to merging (e.g. `df2['col1'] = df2['col1'].astype(str)` and do the same for other columns or check data type with `df2.info()`):

```
df1.merge(df2.assign(col1=df2['col1'].fillna(df2.pop('col2'))), on='col1')

    col1    col3
0   AB0123  abc
1   O678    ghi  #Please note that when reading in the data, I change "0" to "O" as it was dropping the leading "0" and reading data as integer.  See comments.
2   AB0567  dfe
3   O921    jkl  #Please note that when reading in the data, I change "0" to "O" as it was dropping the leading "0" and reading data as integer.  See comments.
4   6752    mno
```

This is the output of the part within `merge`, and what you merge into `df1`:

```
df2.assign(col1=df2['col1'].fillna(df2.pop('col2')))

    col1    col3
0   AB0123  abc
1   AB0567  dfe
2   O678    ghi
3   O921    jkl
4   6752    mno
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. May I know what you mean by  "Please note that I change "0" to "O" as it was dropping the leading "0"

Comment: @royalewithcheese I use `pd.read_clipboard()` to read the stackoverflow data, and it read one of the `col2` of `df2` as integer and dropped the zero, which means that the data didn't merge correctly. It jsut has to do with how I was transferring your StackOverflow data to my jupyter notebook.

Comment: the df's merge on the basis of column1 only it seems...so not getting the corresponding data from col3 to col2 but getting data from col3 related to col1

Answer (score 1):

Lets Try concat df2 and df1 and drop col1.    `df2=df2.assign(col1=df2.col2.astype(str)+df2.col1).drop(columns=['col2'])`

If there are hidden relatonships, then do the following

Make a new datframe `df3` by concatenating `df2.col1` and `df2.col3`.

```
df3=df2.assign(col1=df2.col2.astype(str)+df2.col1).drop(columns=['col2'])
```

Create a dict from `df3`. The dict will have `df3.col1` as key and `df3.col3` as value. Map that to `df1.col1` See below

```
df1['col2']=df1.col1.map(dict(zip(df3.col1,df3.col3)))



   col1_1 col2
0  AB0123  abc
1    O678  ghi
2  AB0567  dfe
3    O921  jkl
4    6752  mno
```